# Trying to run mods in minecraft launcher VoidsWrath and i get the error java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/servlet/ServletContextListener

Tags: java, servlets, minecraft, noclassdeffounderror

(I know close to nothing about coding, just an FYI :))

While trying to launch a modpack, I get the error  java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/servlet/ServletContextListener, which i think leads to java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.servlet.ServletContextListener
Heres the code to show https://pastebin.ubuntu.com/p/4ZCWwgwqNv/

(Sorry for pastebin but i cant get proper code format to work

That seems to be the only error/problem I have, I have tried looking around the internet for how to fix this issue but have gotten nothing (it was all on coding websites like Eclipse, and im doing this on Minecraft) so I have come here now to ask. Thanks for any help.

Comment: Looks like it's caused by Little Maid Mob. Does it still happen if you uninstall that one?

Comment: Thank you, removing littlemaidmob worked! By the way, how did you know it was littlemaidmob causing the problem? Is it complicated, or could I know so I know what the problem is next time? Thanks.

Comment: Most of the entries in your stack trace were either part of Java, part of Minecraft itself, or part of Minecraft's dependencies. In general, those things aren't responsible for crashes. The rest all started with `mmmlibx`, and when I put that into Google, it said that was Little Maid Mob.

Comment: Thank you, I will watch out for key words to troubleshoot myself next time. :)

Answer (score 0):

All I had to do was remove the mod LittleMaidMob and it's associated files, now the game appears to at least launch.